# How to wire ceiling fan/light to two switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I have a black/white/copper cable coming from my box along with a single white cable. I have installed my fan with the receiver for the remote and it is working as long as the previously existing wall switch is turned on. I should note that the installed ceiling fan/light combo work with the remote when the fan wall switch is turned on, it seems not to matter if the light switch is on or not.

I currently have that single white line capped in the ceiling box. Ideally I would like to be able to control the fan/light from the adjustable wall switch and I'm assuming it has something to do with the remaining white wire. Is it possible to do this with the receiver for the remote also installed? I would probably do away with the remote entirely just to have a double wall switch that allows for fan speed and light adjustment.

If needed the fan is the Casablanca Wisp from Home Depot.

Ideas or suggestions?

[The white wire in question is the one in front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qoy3M.jpg)
[image: This is the box with the original wiring to a duel fan/light adjustable switch]

Comment: When several **wires** are combined in a sheath, they are called a **cable**.  The color of wires is somewhat meaningful.  The color of a cable sheath is less important.  A single wire would be disturbing. Can you review and make sure you are using those words correctly?

Comment: To clarify: the romex cable entering the box has the standard black/white/green wiring. Additionally, there is a single white wire entering the box as well. When I uninstalled the original fan this white wire was connected to a green wire coming from the fan (not the ground).

Comment: @somecatchyphrase NM cable is black-white-*bare*.  Green means you either have plastic conduit of some sort, long runs of flexible metal conduit, or MC cable with a separate grounding wire in it

Comment: Also, where does that solo white wire lead? This does sound rather disturbing....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It appears that the single white wire is leading to the switch box in the bedroom. I did not verify the full path when I was in the attic through.

Comment: It seems that this "single white wire" is actually a NM cable, based on the photo of the box innards...

Comment: Also, is getting a different control for your fan in the cards here?